# Combine Server-Side-Blazor with some Offline-Pages (Razor or client-side Blazor) to create a Progressive Web App (PWA)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'd like to use Server-Side-Blazor (SSB) to build a progressive web app (PWA).

I would need a way to handle the server connection being unavailable for an extended period or when the PWA first loads.  In that situation I'd like the app to fail-over to page(s) stored in browser that I previously loaded, for example at startup or in the background.

Could I use client-side Blazor (CSB), or Razor pages to provide that offline support and if so how would the SSB project fail-over to the CSB/Razor Pages?

(This is essentially the same question asked to Scott Hanselman [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatIsBlazorAndWhatIsRazorComponents.aspx) 
by Michael Paine on March 25.2019)

Comment: If client + server blazor can be used in the same app, then the client blazor can be PWA. The question above is: what is the best option to get a useful hybrid-scenario working: leverage Server-Side-Blazor (SSB) for a lot of the project, but if the connection goes down for a long time (or is down when the PWA is activated) then fail-over to page(s) stored in browser that I previously loaded

Comment: Do you know where I can read more about client + server blazor used in the same app ?

Comment: Closest I've seen is this (https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/combining-razor-blazor-pages-single-asp-net-core-3-application ) and then my conjecture/hypothesis (and reason for my question above) that if a Razor Page can call both Blazor-Client and Blazor-Server components, then a PWA should be possible with the Razor or Blazor-Client pages. Something to try.

Comment: @GGleGrand I don't have a solution for this, but it took me a while to understand the question in the first place, so I've added an edit to the question that tries to make it quicker for the reader to actually see what you want answered.  It's a fairly big change though, so do by all means reject the edit if I've accidentally changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: Redoxed down to the essentials. Thanks.